# Elasticsearch No query registered for [exists]]

Tags: elasticsearch

After running the below query, i am getting the exception as No query registered for [exists]. Please help me.

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "match": {
              "_all": {
                "query": "cardio new york"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "gauss": {
            "geo_location": {
              "origin": {
                "lat": 40.7127,
                "lon": -74.0059
              },
              "scale": "100km",
              "offset": "0km",
              "decay": 0.9
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "gauss": {
            "startdate": {
              "origin": "now",
              "scale": "30d",
              "offset": "30d"
            }
          },
          "weight": 0.5
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must": {
              "match": {
                "_all": {
                  "query": "cardio new york"
                }
              }
            },
            "should": {
              "exists": {
                "fields": [
                  "venue",
                  "geo_location"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to filter the search results after the function_score with combining bool match query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`exists` is not a query, it's filter you cannot use it in a `bool` query, instead I would use `bool` filter and wrap only `match` into `query` filter like this:

```
 "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "query": {
          "match": {
            "_all": {
              "query": "cardio new york"
            }
          }
        }
      }, {
        "exists": {
          "fields": [
            "venue",
            "geo_location"
          ]
        }
      }]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying this. Now I am search for the documents which I wanted for.  But I have a scenario where user can search like "cardio 2014", basically wants to conferences of cardiology in 2014.  When i searched that it gives again then 2015 conferences with i high score. How to handle this. Please suggest.

Comment: @sandeep if I answered your original question, please accept my answer and ask a new question separately. The stackoverflow site has a format, which is different from typical forums. It's question answering site. So we should avoid back and forth in comments. Saying that, I think what you are looking for is an `and` operator in your query.

Comment: Thanks you again. My actual problem statement is shared here and I am using the above query . And stuck there. http://stackoverflow.com/q/32499245/5118016

Answer (score 4):

This depends on your version, before version 2.0 you would use the Exists filter, as demonstrated in imotov's answer.

With [2.0 and after](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-dsl-exists-filter.html) exists filter has been replaced by exists query [documentation for current version](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html)

thus the newer exists query would look like the following:

```
{
 "index": "foobars",
 "type": "foo",
 "body": {
  "query": {
   "bool": {
    "must":
        {"exists" : { "field" : "bar" }}
   }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20
 }
}
```